# Double ActionBar appears?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

this is my first app for android, I've been an iPhone dev for 3 years, it's been a change of mindset, and I still find some things odd. First I don't know if this iPhone background might be causing some troubles, but here's what I'm trying to do:

I want to implement an ActionBar with two options working like a TabBar from iOS:

[image: ActionBar]

What I want is that when the user selects an action, some Activity will be presented to the user.

Here's what I'm doing so far (which isn't that much):

- I'm Using ActionBarSherlock, I have 3 activities: myApp, First and Second

myapp.java only creates the ActionBar elements and loads the `activity_first`:

```
package com.example.myApp;

import com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnCreateOptionsMenuListener;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;

public class myApp extends SherlockActivity implements OnCreateOptionsMenuListener {
    ActionBarSherlock mSherlock = ActionBarSherlock.wrap(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setTitle("myApp");
        mSherlock.setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add("First")
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        menu.add("Second")
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        return true;
    }
}
```

The activities have nothing so far, apart from the generated stub:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class First extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);


    }
}
```

So I have 1 Question and 1 problem:

1. **Question**: Is this the correct use of an ActivityBar? I mean, should it be used to switch activities?
2. **Problem**: As you can see in the OnCreate method of myApp class, I'm loading the `activity_first`, It does load the activity, however it loads the ActionBar Twice, like so:

[image]

I don't get why is it being loaded twice. If I remove the line: `mSherlock.setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);` it loads the Bar once, obviously I need to load the activity...

Also I've assigned the NoActionBar theme to the activity_first in the graphical editor of the XML (activity_first.xml), but it doesn't work. What Can I do to load it just once.

**Thank you for your valuable time**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this the correct use of an ActivityBar? I mean, should it be used to switch activities?

You can think of "First" and "Second" as being the equivalent of toolbar buttons in a desktop app. You are welcome to have those action bar items start up activities if you wish.

> As you can see in the OnCreate method of myApp class, I'm loading the activity_first, It does load the activity, however it loads the ActionBar Twice, like so:

Delete this line:

```
ActionBarSherlock mSherlock = ActionBarSherlock.wrap(this);
```

and change `mSherlock.setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);` to just `setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);`. I believe that will clear up your problems.